# Как вернуть определенные поля с помощью VK API, Python и библиотеки vk?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему без проблем возвращаются вот эти поля:

```
profiles = api.users.get(user_id=user_id,
                         fields = "bdate, city, sex, country, nickname,
                                   followers_count, occupation")
```

А остальные не возвращаются?

Т.е. если я напишу:

```
profiles = api.users.get(user_id=user_id,
                         fields = "bdate, city, sex, country, nickname,
                                   followers_count, occupation, activities,
                                   home_town")
```

последние два он не вернет...

В документации вконтакте написано, что для некоторых полей нужен `token`, но те поля, для которых он нужен, возвращаются без проблем.
Очень нужны остальные поля...)

Comment: Может быть такое что их попросту нет?

Comment: нет, к сожалению они есть, и по идее, даже незаполненные пользователем поля должны возвращаться, только пустыми...

Comment: Проверьте версию VK API, которую вы используете или точнее, которую использует ваша библиотека на питоне. Вполне возможно, что проблема кроется в ней..

Comment: спасибо, стоит последняя...

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов вк апи на питоне, по сути это `requests` с урлами и хедерами вк, вот Вам по-простому, сверьте урлы, посмотрите подробно что приходит, возможно Вы что-то пропустили:

```
 def get_user(vk_id, access_token):
    url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={0}&fields=photo_400_orig&v=5.60".format(vk_id)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-Encoding': 'utf-8'}

    res = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/account.getProfileInfo?user_ids={0}&access_token={1}'.
                       format(vk_id, access_token), headers=headers)
    print(res.json())
    if 'error' not in res.json():
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            photo = response.json()['response'][0]['photo_400_orig']
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            photo = None
        user = res.json()['response']
        name = user['first_name']
        vk_id = 'vk_' + str(vk_id)
        sex = user['sex'] or 0

        if 'home_town' in user:
            city = user['home_town']
        elif 'city' in user:
            city = user['city']['title']
        else:
            city = None

        birth = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(user['bdate'], '%d.%m.%Y').timetuple()) or 0
        return {'name': name, 'sex': sex, 'birth': birth, 'city': city, 'photo': photo, 'id': vk_id}
    return False
```